# Trying to build easy application with database

Tags: java, database

I am trying to build an application just for save records and delete them for now, I new with Java and database, when I save it works fine but when I try to remove I got an error:

```
Comparisons between 'LONG VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' and 
    'LONG VARCHAR (UCS_BASIC)' are not supported.
```

---

```
private void SaveBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test", "app", "testcode");
        st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO APP.UNTI(ID,NAME) VALUES(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, J1.getText().trim());
        ps.setString(2, J2.getText().trim());
        if(ps.executeUpdate()>0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insert succusful");
        }
    }catch(SQLException xmp){
       System.out.println("error");
    }
}                                       

private void RemoveBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
      try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Test", "app", "testcode");
        st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();            
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM UNTI WHERE NAME = ? ");
        System.out.println("ok");
        ps.setString(1,J2.getText().trim());           
        if(ps.executeUpdate() > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insert succusful");
        }
    }catch(SQLException xmp){
       System.out.println(xmp.getMessage()  );
    }catch(NullPointerException xmp){
        System.out.println(xmp.getMessage()  );
    }

}
```

Comment: BTW - having `System.out.println("error");` as the only thing inside a `catch` statement is not helping. Do something more useful like `xmp.printStackTrace();`. Do that for ***every*** catch which does not implement logging (a better alternative).

Comment: ok thx i add this and its crush on this line         PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM UNTI WHERE NAME = ? "); but i dont know why

Comment: Could you try `"DELETE FROM UNTI WHERE TRIM(NAME) = TRIM(?) "` ?

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions. Your method names should go camelCase()

Answer (score 1):

You can not compare long varchar, just as you can not index them.

[Comparison table documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj58560.html)

Picture taken from documentation (link provided), note that long varchar can not be compared to long varchar.

[image: Comparison table]

[Derby issue about this already registered](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-5130)

**Suggestion:**

I suggest using varchar or CLOB instead of long varchar, depending on your data.

Comment: @Koby if you're happy with the answer, you might accept this, so it would be clear that the thread has a working answer.